# How to numerically integrate this function near x = 0?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, special-functions

I'm trying to NIntegrate[] the following integration: Let's define a function

$F_\delta(x) = 1 - \Phi[\Phi^{-1}[1 - x] - \delta], \ \ x \in (0, 1)$

where $\delta > 0, \Phi(x)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

The integration I would like to get is:

$\int_0^1 F_{\delta_1}(0.05 + 0.95x) d F_{\delta_2}(x)$

NIntegrate[] works well when $\delta_1, \delta_2$ is not large. However, when $\delta_1, \delta_2$ is large, for example, $\delta_1 = 5, \delta_2 = 10$, the integration would overflow near $x = 0$ as $f_{\delta}(0) \rightarrow \infty$ as $\delta$ increases.

I know the limit of the integration should be 1 as $\delta_1, \delta_2$ increases, but my task is to give a plot of the integration value as $\delta$ increases, so I need to seek a way to evaluate the value or at least some kind of approximation even when $\delta_1, \delta_2$ is rather large.

Here are the code I used for Mathematica:

```
f[x_, d_] := Exp[-(d^2/2) + d*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x]]
F[x_, c_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x] - c] 
NIntegrate[F[0.05 + 0.95 x, 5] * f[x, 10], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: please post Mathematica code you used.

Comment: Sure! Let me post the Mathematica code.

Comment: Rationalize function and play with MaxRecursion, WorkingPrecision, AccuracyGoal ...  `NIntegrate[F[5/100 + 95/100 x, 5]*f[x, 10], {x, 0, 1}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`  yields `0.999603384995483853038609328216`

Comment: MaxRecursion works well for a single point, but when I tried List contour plot for (\delta_1, \delta_2) taking value in unit square, even MaxRecursion -> 15 is very slow. Is there any faster way for List contour plot?

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, d_] := 
 Exp[-(d^2/2) + d*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x]]
F[x_, c_] := 
 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x] - c]

NIntegrate[F[1/20 + 19/20 x, 5]*f[x, 10], {x, 0, 1},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* 0.999603384995484 *)

int[δ_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  F[1/20 + 19/20 x, δ]*f[x, 10], {x, 0, 1},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

AbsoluteTiming@ListLinePlot[
  Table[{δ, int[δ]}, {δ, 2, 10, 1/4}],
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Using `Plot` is much slower

```
AbsoluteTiming@Plot[int[δ], {δ, 2, 10},
  PlotRange -> All,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]